# Adding filename and line number to Monolog output

Tags: php, monolog

Couldn't find a way to add a the file name and the line number from which the log function was called.
I'm using a simple StreamHandler:

```
$this->log = new Logger('APP');
$this->log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('/logs/app.log', Logger::DEBUG));
```

and I would like an output of something like that:

```
[2017-12-27 12:38:58 filename.php:1234] APP.DEBUG: test
```

or any other format which includes the file name and line number.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: `Monolog/Processor/IntrospectionProcessor` can add file/line/class/function fields to your log data, but you'd need to write a custom formatter to then get the specific output you're after.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I looked for.

Answer (score 5):

It's late, but I figured out how to do it and I'm gonna post to someone else.

First, you need to create your own [Processor](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#processors) with a new record key to be parsed (I named it as `file_info`):

```php
class MyProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param  array $record
     * @return array
     */
    public function __invoke(array $record)
    {
      $info = $this->findFile();
      $record['file_info'] = $info['file'] . ':' . $info['line'];
      return $record;
    }

    public function findFile() {
      $debug = debug_backtrace();
      return [
        'file' => $debug[3] ? basename($debug[3]['file']) : '',
        'line' => $debug[3] ? $debug[3]['line'] : ''
      ];
    }
}
```

I used [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.debug-backtrace.php) to get the third element basename file and line, I'm not sure if it will work every time though.

Then, create your Logger with a custom [LineFormatter](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php) (I got this part from [here](http://seldaek.github.io/monolog/doc/01-usage.html#customizing-the-log-format)):

```php
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// the default date format is "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"
$dateFormat = "Y n j, g:i a";
// the default output format is "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n"
$output = "[%datetime% %file_info%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n";
// finally, create a formatter
$formatter = new LineFormatter($output, $dateFormat);
// Create a handler
$stream = new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/my_app.log', Logger::DEBUG);
$stream->setFormatter($formatter);
// bind it to a logger object
$myLogger = new Logger('mylogger');
$myLogger->pushHandler($stream);
```

Now, you can use `$myLogger->error('Foo');` and the result will be:

```
[2021 2 24, 6:19 pm ProductController.php:50] mylogger.ERROR: Foo [] []
```

Comment: I would like to implement this solution in my code but it's unclear what you do with MyProcessor.

Comment: To add the own info to a log record using Monolog, you can use a custom processor. 
Monolog allows you to attach processors to the log records before they are handled. 
These processors can modify the records or add additional information to them. 
In your case, you want to add the file info. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

`$errorStream = new StreamHandler('/var/www/logs/error.parser.log', Level::Debug);`
`$errorStream->pushProcessor(new MyProcessor());`
`$errorStream->pushProcessor(new MemoryUsageProcessor());`